# How to select rows for a specific date, ignoring time in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Given a table with a datetime column, how do I query for rows where the date matches the value I specify but ignores the time portion?

For example, `select * from sales where salesDate = '11/11/2010'`

For this query we don't care about the time. Other queries require the time component so we can't store only the date component.

Thanks!

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can remove the time component when comparing:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sales 
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, salesDate))) = '11/11/2010'
```

Another approach is to change the select to cover all the time between the start and end of the date:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sales 
-- WHERE salesDate BETWEEN '11/11/2010 00:00:00.00' AND '11/11/2010 23:59:59.999'
WHERE salesDate BETWEEN '2020-05-18T00:00:00.00' AND '2020-05-18T23:59:59.999'
```

Comment: I am not getting result with yours solution

Comment: Sorry to hear that. You sure your date ranges are right and that data that matches them exists in the database?

Comment: could do:
SELECT * FROM sales WHERE CAST(salesDate as DATE) = '11/11/2010'

Answer (score 16):

I know it's been a while on this question, but I was just looking for the same answer and found this seems to be the simplest solution:

```
select * from sales where datediff(dd, salesDate, '20101111') = 0
```

I actually use it more to find things within the last day or two, so my version looks like this:

```
select * from sales where datediff(dd, salesDate, getdate()) = 0
```

And by changing the 0 for today to a 1 I get yesterday's transactions, 2 is the day before that, and so on.  And if you want everything for the last week, just change the equals to a less-than-or-equal-to:

```
select * from sales where datediff(dd, salesDate, getdate()) <= 7
```

Comment: Nice solution. Confirmed to work with h2 db if you change the date format to 'yyyy-MM-dd'.

Comment: what is `dd` here?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM sales WHERE CAST(salesDate AS date) = '2010-10-10'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old topic, but I managed to do it in this simple way:

```
select count(*) from `tablename`
where date(`datecolumn`) = '2021-02-17';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from sales where salesDate between '11/11/2010' and '12/11/2010' --if using dd/mm/yyyy
```

The more correct way to do it:

```
DECLARE @myDate datetime
SET @myDate = '11/11/2010'
select * from sales where salesDate>=@myDate and salesDate<dateadd(dd,1,@myDate)
```

If only the date is specified, it means total midnight. If you want to make sure intervals don't overlap, switch the between with a pair of `>=` and `<`

you can do it within one single statement, but it's just that the value is used twice.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select 
  * 
from sales 
where salesDate >= '11/11/2010' 
  AND salesDate < (Convert(datetime, '11/11/2010') + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  * 
from sales 
where 
  dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, salesDate), 0) = '11/11/2010'
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE date LIKE '%2022-11-19%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this for Postgres SQL.

```
SELECT * FROM sales
WHERE EXTRACT(DATE FROM salesDate) = '2010-11-11';

SELECT * FROM sales
WHERE CAST(salesDate AS DATE) = '2010-11-11';
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot simpler then that, just convert the datetime to a date:

```
SELECT * FROM sales
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, salesDate) = '2010-11-11';
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
true
select cast(salesDate as date) [date] from sales where salesDate = '2010/11/11'
false
select cast(salesDate as date) [date] from sales where salesDate = '11/11/2010'
```