# how i can retrieve rows by specific date in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I'm working in project for by PHP and SQL Server.

The owner want from me  design page show only users who register in same day

i.e., if today 11-3-2011 i want show only all users who register in 11-3-2011

The table is:

```
id  username  date

1   john      11\3\2011
2   sara      11\3\2011
3   john      5\1\2011
4   kreem     1\2\2011
```

i make it by mysql

```
where DATE_ADD( items.created_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY ) > NOW()
```

this cable of code show data which only insert in same day thats mean if today 10-4-2011 it will show only data which insert in 10-4-2011 if i today 15-4-2011 and im dose not insert any thing it will not show any thing, how i can build code like this in sql server? hope to be my question clear and understand

Comment: What version of SQL Server? What datatype is the `date` column? Does it have any time component?

Comment: i use sql server 2002....thx for help but that was not i need i make it by mysql but can do it by mssql look to this code `DATE_ADD( items.created_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY ) > NOW()` this is mysql code show data which inserted in same day with same date

Comment: @user - There isn't a SQL Server 2002. The options are 2000,2005,2008. You haven't answered my other questions either.

Comment: Please take a look at these answes:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156011/how-to-select-rows-for-a-specific-date-ignoring-time

Answer (score 5):

```
select id, userName
from YourTable
where CAST(date AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Function [GETDATE()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx) returns the current date and time.

[CAST(column as TYPE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) will threat DateTime as just Date to omit differences in Time

Comment: This will work in SQL Server 2008 or later. And I guess that `CAST(date AS DATE)` will make an index on `date` useless, if it's not already of data type `DATE` but then the cast is unnecessary.

Comment: @Mikael: Will index on calculated value make sense in this case?

Comment: @Mikael - Casting on `Date` **is** sargable. See http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/526431/make-more-functions-sargable Obviously impossible to tell how suitable this is for the OP without additional information.

Comment: @Martin – That is great, makes life easier when dealing with datetime. @abatishchev – It is not necessary with index on calculated value. I did not know that casting datetime to date is sargable.

Answer (score 5):

For getting today's date record:

```
select * from tablename where date column between '2011-10-25 00:00:00' And '2011-10-25 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 2):

`select * from yourtable where date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),101)` // hope this will be helpful to get current date value..

Answer (score 1):

This query compares only the date piece of today, ignoring the time.  It works in MS SQL Server, I'm not sure about other implimentations:

```
select *
from YourTable
where convert(datetime, floor(convert(float, GETDATE()))) = [date]
```

Comment: What for so much operations when you can just `CAST(GETDATE() as Date)` to get only date-part and omit time-part

Comment: I guess I learned a bad practice from http://leftlobed.wordpress.com/2008/05/03/archive-getting-the-date-portion-of-a-datetime-type-in-sql-t-sql-use-floats-and-floor/ and http://www.stillnetstudios.com/comparing-dates-without-times-in-sql-server/

Comment: I see there are a lot of [variants](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/10/sql-server-retrieve-select-only-date-part-from-datetime-best-practice/)

Comment: After further review, I suspect your version only works in SQL 2008, and many applications want to be compatible with SQL Server 2005 still.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from YourTable
where
  [date] >= '20110311' and
  [date] < '20110312'
```

If you want it for today (always) you can use this

```
select *
from YourTable
where
  [date] >= dateadd(d, datediff(d, 0, getdate()), 0) and
  [date] < dateadd(d, datediff(d, 0, getdate())+1, 0)
```

Last 10 days.

```
select *
from YourTable
where
  [date] >= dateadd(d, datediff(d, 0, getdate())-9, 0)
```

**Edit 1** Query with sample data and result

Table definition

```
create table users
  (name varchar(20),
   user_register_date datetime)
```

Data

```
insert into users values ('user today', getdate())
insert into users values ('user yesterday', getdate()-1)
insert into users values ('user 9 days ago', getdate()-9)
insert into users values ('user 10 days ago', getdate()-10)
```

Query

```
select *
from users
where user_register_date >= dateadd(d, datediff(d, 0, getdate())-9, 0)
```

Result

```
name                 user_register_date
-------------------- -----------------------
user today           2011-04-14 08:29:28.407
user yesterday       2011-04-13 08:29:28.410
user 9 days ago      2011-04-05 08:29:28.410
```

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson: I think he wants to have a function working every day, not only for the specified day...

Comment: yes Mikael Eriksson i need function run automatic like say before

Comment: what is [date]? is that function and what is d after ( did you mean column name?

Comment: @user – [Date] is a field in YourTable called Date. Since Date is also a data type you can use the brackets to not have any doubts to what you mean. The `d` is a parameter to dateadd and datediff specifying that the functions should work with days.

Comment: sorry, i cant get it........lets me tell i have table his name users and column which include dates his name user_register_date should i do  like this =>  `select *
from users 
where
  user_register_date  >= dateadd(d, datediff(d, 0, getdate())-9, 0)` ? please fix it if i have wrong

Comment: @user – Your query is correct. I have updated the answer with your query and some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from YourTable
WHERE cast(convert(varchar(10),yourdate,101) as datetime) = 
cast(convert(varchar(10),[any day you want],101) as datetime)
```

Hope this helps. Just replace [any day you want] with a date or datetime value

The CAST function is equivalent to the CONVERT function, except convert allows for some formatting options. In my example, I simply trimmed off the time from the date.