# SQL Server 2008 search for date

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, date, indexing

I need to search rows entered on a specific date.

However the datatype of column I need to search on is `datetime`, and the datatype of argument is `Date`.

I can use the the query like

```
Select result 
from table 
where
     convert(date, Mycolumn) = @selectedDate
```

but this would affect the SARGability of the query and will not use indexes created on `mycolumn`.

I was trying to use the following query:

```
Select result 
from table 
where  
  Mycolumn 
       BETWEEN @selectedDate AND Dateadd(s, -1, Dateadd(D, 1, @selectedDate))
```

However this does not work since the `@selectedDate` is Date type and a second can't be added or removed.

Can someone help me with a working query?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156011/how-to-select-rows-for-a-specific-date-ignoring-time][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select result 
from table 
where  
    Mycolumn >= @selectedDate 
AND Mycolumn < Dateadd(D, 1, @selectedDate)
```

Comment: Thanks !! this will do what I wanted :)

Answer (score 2):

It is my understanding that using:

```
convert(date, Mycolumn) = @selectedDate
```

is SARGable.  It will use the index on Mycolumn (if one exists).  This can easily be confirmed by using the execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do these searches a lot, you could add a computed, persisted column that does the conversion to `DATE`, put an index on it and then search on that column

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
ADD DateOnly AS CAST(MyColumn AS DATE) PERSISTED
```

Since it's persisted, it's (re-)calculated only when the `MyColumn` value changes, e.g. it's not a "hidden" call to a stored function. Since it's persisted, it can also be indexed and used just like any other regular column:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX01_YourTable_DateOnly ON dbo.YourTable(DateOnly)
```

and then do:

```
 SELECT result FROM dbo.YourTable WHERE DateOnly = @SelectedDate
```

Since that additional info is stored in the table, you'll be using a bit more storage - so you're doing the classic "space vs. speed" trade-off; you need a bit more space, but you get more speed out of it.