# Fetching record of last 48 hrs from SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table1 with with the columns `DATETIME`, `ID` and `Status`.

I will call my stored procedure after specific hours and I want to fetch records of last 48 non weekend hours.

I tried to do it by writing case for each day of `getdate()`.

I want to know what is the best way to do this.

Comment: Why don't you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156011/how-to-select-rows-for-a-specific-date-ignoring-time-in-sql-server

Comment: Non-weekend hours? Does that mean Saturdays and Sundays are not counted? Or is it after 5pm Friday to 8am Monday?

Comment: saturday sunday not counted

Answer (score 1):

To avoid weekends, you can use a `case` or other logic in the `where`.  Your logic isn't 100% clear on what to do on weekend days.  But here is an approach:

```
where (datename(wk, getdate()) in ('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday') and datetime >= dateadd(hour, 48 + 48, getdate()) ) or
      (datename, wk, getdate()) in ('Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday') and datetime >= dateadd(hour, 48, getdate()) or
      (datename , wk, getdate()) in ('Saturday') and datetime >= dateadd(hour, 24 + 48, getdate());
```