# SSRS date/time parameter

Tags: sql-server, datetime, reporting-services, parameters

I have a ssrs report that has a date/time parameter that allows the user to select the date when running report. how to I get it to exclude the time part of the date field.

currently the field in the db is a date/time field so when I run query

```
select count(*) from table where date <= @dateparameter
```

it is not including records where the time part of field is greater than 00.00.00

how can I ignore the time part so all records are returned for that date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select rows for a specific date, ignoring time in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156011/how-to-select-rows-for-a-specific-date-ignoring-time-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest (and probably best performance) solution would be to add a day to the date passed by the user amd change the `<=` to `<`:

```
select count(*) from table where date < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @dateparameter)
```